# Delete particular string in JTextarea

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextarea

I have developing application with AWT, and I use JTextarea for displaying some string values, values are  retrieving from database. In this i want delete particular string in JTextarea, I have tried a lot,but i cant.Plz Give me the suggestion.
My code

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : checkList.entrySet()) {
                            String client_Name=entry.getKey();
                            if(!liHashMap.containsKey(client_Name))
                            {
                             checkList.remove(client_Name);
                            taNames.setText("");//But It removes all values
                       //here i want to remove the particular client_Name from 
                            JTextarea.
                            }
                         }
```

Comment: *"developing application with AWT, and I use JTextarea"*  Then you are very confused.  [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) is the **Swing** equivalent of the AWT based **[`TextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextArea.html)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
taNames.setText( taNames.getText.replaceAll( client_Name, "" ) )
```

Comment: Thanx..But i should not override the content, just delete the particular value itself.Is it possible..?

Comment: @kanna You could use the `replaceRange` method. But this involves calculating the range. Why is the solution I proposed not good enough ?